# Opening a window from an iFrame to its parent using a post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found similar problems on this site, but none of the solutions seem to work for my specific problem.

I have an iFrame embedded on my site. Inside this iFrame is a form with an input field that uses a 3rd party mailing service. When this form is submitted, a confirmation message pops up.

I need this message to appear in the main page inside of a different iFrame with an ID of mailingIframe. Below is the code I have at the moment:

```
<form action="http://blockdot.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=434e0b545d0c86c1ccd5aee9c&amp;id=5a445105c5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" **target="parent.document.getElementById('mailingIframe')"**
```

Comment: Is the iframe in a different domain?

Comment: Mate you haven't posted the code. Post it so we can help you! :)

Comment: You can not target an element on the page, you can target a window/iframe, but not an element.

Comment: I am trying to pass it into an iFrame with an ID of mailingIframe. And yes they are in the same domain, and on the same page.

Comment: what I usually do is I call a function defined in the parent (main) program (like `parent.thefunction(data)`, and this function can access the other frame since its page contains it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your form action with `action="javascript:;"` and then make a javascript function which is called on the onclick event of your submit button. This function will basically do the validation and the data submission and its return will be to put your validation/procedure message to the contents of your "mailingIframe" area, like `$("#mailingIframe").html('YOUR MESSAGE!');`